# Meteor Mongo add subdocument

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection documents `MasterPropinsis` like this :

```
{
    "_id": "4HSb7bbjFBzRSftXu",
    "nama": "Yogyakarta",
    "kabupaten": [
        {
            "id": "KulonProgo",
            "nama": "Kulon Progo",
            "kecamatan": [{ "nama": "Kalibawang" },{ "nama": "Nanggulan" }]
        },
        {
            "id": "Sleman",
            "nama": "Sleman",
            "kecamatan": [{ "nama": "Depok" },{ "nama": "Berbah" }]
        },
        {
            "id": "Bantul",
            "nama": "Bantul",
            "kecamatan": []
        }
    ]
}
```

At `kabupaten:Bantul`, I want to Add subdocument `kecamantan:XXX`, with this code :

```
Masterpropinsis.update(
    {
        _id: Session.get('idKabupaten').toString(),
        'kabupaten.id': Session.get('idKecamatan').replace(" ", "")
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            'kabupaten.kecamatan': {
                nama: nama,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                createBy: CreateBy,
                createByID: CreateByid
            }
        }
    },
    {
        validate: true
    });
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]
```

Comment: you need to change this `{_id:Session.get('idKabupaten').toString(),'kabupaten.id':Session.get('idKecamatan').replace(" ", "")}` if you're doing it from the client you can update only by `_id` removing the `kabupatan.id` part will make it work, you need to specify `kabupatan.id` inside the modifier not the selector.

Comment: Sorry Mr @MarkUretsky, i cant imagine what your means. Can you give me example. Thanks you verry much

Comment: i added an answer maybe it will help you now? If not if you can more on why you add sub documents I might recommend better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example try this

```
var docId = Session.get('idKabupaten'); // usally toString is not nesserry unless you do something unusual 

Masterpropinsis.update({_id: docId }, {
    $push: {
      'kabupaten.kecamatan': {
        nama: nama,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        createBy: CreateBy,
        createByID: CreateByid
      }
    }
}); // validate true also is the default unless again you do something unusual
```

you can see we only supply `{_id: docId}` in the selector the error says in client you can only update by the ID in the server you can do any selector. Also hopefully you can have Allow/Deny rules to allow updates from the client? http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow

Comment: Thanks Mr. @MarkUretsky, i have try but show error like this :
Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

Comment: Can you show me more of your code something is wrong it should work or even better can you create a meteorpad for the code I could fix it that way